# SQL Server: Cursor in Dynamic Proc, Insert errors b/c of Null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I'll do my best to explain..  I'm restoring information from one table to another.  i.e. the actual row has been deleted so the PK is now gone.  A backup of the table exists elsewhere.  I have manipulated the format to get the correct columns in the correct order.

I setup a cursor to get each value and insert. The insert actually occurs within the cursor looping area.

So the problem I run into is that it inserts one value at a time as it loops through.. The first insert is the PK and boom.  Some of the values in the table I'm testing do not allow null values.  So the second only the primary key is inserted it breaks b/c I've violated the table constraints. Of course I'm putting those values in later.. but they're executed one statement at a time.  ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to do this using a cursor? If a backup exists, I'd think you could import all the missing data at once. Please show us your table structure.

Comment: this stored proc is dynamic.  information is fed in from .net to define the table and backup table.

Comment: Even so, once you have the definition you should be able to implement a set-based solution. If there's no way to do that, you'll have to disable the constraints and then re-enable them. Because SQL Server expects a set-based solution, I don't think you can update a row bit by bit while those constraints are enabled.

Comment: but there is no way to turn off column constraints temporarily just Foreign Key etc.. So it sounds like it would have to be a set based solution.

Comment: Can you put the data in a staging table with no constraints....then have a "post" event that says "move everything in staging to real".  Then you'd get setbased, but be able to keep your row by row (and column by column) functionality in tact.

Comment: Because....wow........RBAR (row by agonizing row) and CBAC (column by agonizing column) is pretty .. pretty crazy.  So without rewriting everything, the staging table idea sounds better to me.

Comment: actually that's what I'm working on this second.. I already have a table setup w/ the column names, if I can get the datatypes set it should work.  Then the temp would be an exact copy of what I need.